# AWS QuickSight/SPICE: Specify Data Type with CSV File

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a Spice/QuickSight that has a CSV as a source.  One of the fields in the CSV has fields with numbers and text.  When importing into SPICE manually, rows fail to import, and it's because it thinks the `Tractor Number` field is numeric and not alphnumeric.

How do I specify *programmatically* to Spice/Quicksight that the field `Tractor Number` is alphanumeric and not numbers only?

Comment: What you mean programmatically? Are you looking for UI solution or some kind of CLI/API solution?

Comment: @PankajSaini I would like to do this using a CLI/API solution as this is going to be an automated process

Comment: Not sure how to do it using _API_. When defining new data source, **Quicksight UI** provides option for me to change the data type.. and then it imports all rows. I just did a small test, even the failed rows get imported correctly with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Quicksight CLI then you can use the [create-data-set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/create-data-set.html) command and inside of that you can specify the name and data type of the columns in the --physical-table-map -> [InputColumns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_InputColumn.html) parameter:

> InputColumns -> (list)
>
> The column schema of the table.
>
> (structure)
>
> Metadata for a column that is used as the input of a transform
> operation.
>
> Name -> (string)
>
> The name of this column in the underlying data source. Type ->
> (string)
>
> The data type of the column.

As for doing it via the upload file UI / command / S3 with manifest route...I have not found ANY way to enforce automatic recognition of a column type as a string type if it contains only numbers. The Quicksight dataset creation process in the UI completely ignores things like quoting the numbers etc and always sets the column as integer :(

As suggested above, You can upload the file once, manually change the column type to string and thereafter it will remain a string type column whenever you upload a new version of the file.